Any ideas what could be causing a "anydesk" website not to show
The website https://anydesk.com/en-gb
Will not show on my PC, a wired connection
but will show on my sons (same network) wired connection
but will not be on my wife's (same network) wireless connection.
All other websites appear to work :(
I'm at a loss
Have tried...

Chrome - Not work
Chrome incognito - Not work
Edge - Not work
My Phone, connected to the house's wireless network - Not work
My Phone, connected to the phone network - WILL Work
Tried turning off Avast
Tried turning off Defender

My current guess is the wireless router.
House network...

Internet... Wireless Router...
Port 1 - Server
Port 2 - 8 port switch to PCS and stuff
Port 3
Port 4

Any pointers, please?

What does show up instead? Error message? Blank page? Some other website?

ping and traceroute might be helpful

Have you tried to reset the router and switch? Are the wired connections to the switch? What models are the router and switch?

Try pinging one of their IP addresses, e.g., 18.238.192.84 . If the ping succeeds, then the issue is most likely that DNS lookup for https://anydesk.com/en-gb is failing.

Try clearing the DNS cache of the machine(s).
If that fails to resolve the issue, try assigning a specific DNS resolver, such as Cloudflare, Google Public DNS or another DNS public resolver.

If all above fails, then your internet service provider (ISP) may be blocking that site. You can test that by going to a public library, internet cafe or other place for an internet connection. If your devices can reach Anydesk there, talk with your ISP.

On the money!!! My ISP talktalk had a "muppetry" button enabled "Scam Protection". Doesnt explain why my sons worked though? He must have a VPN for his p£$£. Many thanks all!
